# TYPE_STEP_COUNTER sensor not found on a real device(Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, sensormanager

Hello I`m doing step counter.
In manifest I added the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
```

I also added a check in the onCreate method:

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
        //ask for permission
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION}, 1);
    }
```

But my `countSensor` is null:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    running = true;
    Sensor countSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    if(countSensor != null){
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,countSensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sensor not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I am using a real device(Samsung Galaxy A30). Who knows what's the problem? Thank you!